# CSS Style Not Working With ID

Tags: asp.net, css

I am using `asp.net/C#` for my project.Currently i have a `default.aspx` page and a master page.The `default.aspx` page has many controls , and for each control i have defined `class` and `id`.  The problem i am facing is that when i apply `style` to a particular control using the `class` , the styles are reflected properly, and when i do that using the id of the control the style is not reflected.
I rectified the issue but i dont know how to solve that.
For instance,
I have a `textbox` with `id="txtCustNo"` ,, when i apply style like

```
#txtCustNo{border:1px solid red}
```

it doesnot reflect ,,,when i apply style like `#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCustNo` it shows the changes , however the id is `txtCustNo`..Can somebody point me out where am i going wrong.Thanks .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ID on server controls is automatically generated and is not the same as the generated ID on the client side.

You can find what the generated ID with be with this: <%# txtCustNo.ClientID %>

ASP.NET 4 supports a new ClientIDMode property on the Control base class.  The ClientIDMode property indicates how controls should generate client ID values when they render.  The ClientIDMode property supports four possible values:

1. AutoID—Renders the output as in .NET 3.5 (auto-generated IDs which will still render prefixes like ctrl00 for compatibility)
2. Predictable (Default)— Trims any “ctl00” ID string and if a list/container control concatenates child ids (example: id=”ParentControl_ChildControl”)
3. Static—Hands over full ID naming control to the developer – whatever they set as the ID of the control is what is rendered (example: id=”JustMyId”)
4. Inherit—Tells the control to defer to the naming behavior mode of the parent container control

When using ASP.Net before 4.0 you have to live with the auto generated ID's.

For more info on the 4.0 features see this link.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Comment: ,,, that means i need to use generated id's for styling right?? ex ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCustNo is the right way ,, is it

Comment: Yes. You need to target the generated IDs.

Answer (score 3):

The client ID is not equal to the [`ID` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id.aspx) of a `runat="server"` control. To get the ID on the client, you can use the [`ClientID` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx).

On newer ASP.NET versions (starting with version 4), there is also a [`ClientIDMode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) to control the generation.

So to solve your issue, you could either set `ClientIDMode` to `ClientIDMode.Static` or somehow access the `ClientID` property from code behind and put this value into your CSS definition.

Alternatively you could also:

- Put the text box in some container control (e.g. a `div`) that has *no* `runat="server"` and put an ID into this container control, changing your CSS to e.g. `#txtContainer input{border:1px solid red}`
- Use the [`CssClass` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) of your text box and use this class in your CSS file, instead of the ID.

Comment: thanks a lot. so i tried ussing cssclass property and it is working , that means i will have to create cssclass for each control to apply styles individually right????

Comment: @freebird You could do this, yes. On the other hand, do you really need each control look different? If not, re-using the CSS class on multiple controls is totally valid and in my opinion a good way to go.

Comment: ,, ya i dont need to style each control differently ,, so i guess i will use cssclass for my purpose , however some controls i will have to apply style to them individually that time i should use generatedid of the control or inline syle ,,, m i proceeding in a rightway ???thank you

Comment: decoupling is always a good idea. I would vote against inline style and rather prefer external CSS.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are using Visual Studio 2010 you can set the clientID mode of the control to`ClientIDMode="Static"`
2. I would advise you to use CSS along with a skin file
3. Also, if you are trying to style a control via CSS, just wrap a div around it & then apply styles like (these get applied to all inputs inside that div)

   > ## divId input {
   >
   > ```
   >           width: 100px;
   >      }
   > ```
   >
   > [ASP.NET Themes and Skins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx)  [Themes & Skins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11886/Themes-and-Skins-in-ASP-NET-2-0)

Comment: I am using visual studio 2008 ,,, so i guess i wont be able to use ClientIDMode right ???? so could you tell me how can i use CSS with a skin file ,,, thanks

Comment: You will need Visual Studio 2010 to target .Net 4.0. There is a simple way to find out the generated clientIDs though. See my posted answer.

Comment: You can point 3 in my post, styling with divs or you can use a skin file