# css does't work for two ids

Tags: asp.net, css

I have this aspx

```
<div id="tabs-1">
    <table id="BookingTable" runat="server">
        <tr><th>ID</th><th>PlanTime</th></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <div id="circleG" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom:50px;"><div id="circleG_1" class="circleG"></div><div id="circleG_2" class="circleG"></div><div id="circleG_3" class="circleG"></div></div>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
      <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" runat="server" >
        </p> 
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Button id="BookingForDate" runat="server" OnClick="BookingForDate_Click" Text="Search"/> 
        <table id="DateBookingTable" runat="server" >
        <tr><th>ID</th><th>PlanTime</th></tr>
    </table>
      </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
  </div>
```

This is my css:

```
#BookingTable, #DateBookingTable{
        overflow:hidden;
        border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    }
```

Although I already make this `#BookingTable, #DateBookingTable`, the css works for just the first ID, not the second, why please?

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/KB42V/. DarkHippo's comment is probably where you should be looking

Comment: @3rror404 the table's name is not being changed

Comment: Post the generated html instead of your .net

Comment: can you share a live link?

Comment: @3rror404 suddenly, it works, i just removed the cash from my browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID on server controls is automatically generated and is not the same as the generated ID on the client side.

**Here is the complete reference about your problem:**
[CSS Style Not Working With ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629425/css-style-not-working-with-id)

Answer (score 0):

Check the generated HTML source in a browser to make sure that DateBookingTable isn't being renamed by the .Net compiler into something less intelligible.

Comment: I checked, and it has the same exact name

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
 #MainContent_BookingTable, #MainContent_DateBookingTable{
            overflow:hidden;
            border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
        }
```